# The import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver conflicts with a type defined in the same file

Tags: java

While trying to set chrome browser for selenium testing I am facing this conflict, please help !

Comment: The fully qualified name solved the conflict, Thanks !

Comment: Then validate the answer that helped you!

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Fully qualify the name of the selenium-provided class, avoiding the need for the conflicting import:

   ```
   ChromeDriver myChromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(); // One from same package
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver theirChromeDriver = new org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver();  // One from selenium
   ```
2. Rename your `ChromeDriver` class.

Answer (score 0):

You could have named your .java file as TakesScreenshot.java this is the reason you got the issue. Just rename your file from TakesScreenshot.java to TakesScreenshotDemo.java or sth else.